# Looking for holiday data of Saudi Arabia and Bangladesh/Pakistan from 1950s until now

Tags: data-request, uses-of-open-data

It is okay if the data is not downloadable but viewable. But I need to compare dates of a particular holiday being celebrated in these two/three countries and plot a graph.

I looked into timeanddate they do not have data for Bangladesh/Pakistan from early times.

Comment: You could ask the governments directly, try searching google books for "list of pakistan holidays" or "almanac 1950" (both with no quotes), or several other variations. However, because google provides only snippets, you may have to go down to an actual physical library and see if you can find a source that lists holidays annually like https://www.dawn.com/news/1332229 has. You could also look through digitized newspaper archives, either from Pakistan/etc or with headlines like "Pakistan celebrates".

Comment: Note that https://www.calendar-yearly.com/ claims to list these, but I wouldn't trust it too far, since it lists holidays for 1945 (for example), before either Pakistan or Bangladesh existed.